# sync Nevernote (Evernote clone) notes to my own server

Tags: sync, local, evernote

Supposedly, it used to be possible to sync Evernote notes to your own server. I would like to use the open source clone NeverNote, to sychronize to my own server. Is there a way of doing this?

[Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=611756) is another person asking the a similar question in another forum.
[Here](http://www.evernote.com/pub/baumgarr/nevernote#n=a52faa6f-d9c7-4505-ae03-4c25b95ebeb4&b=2dee229e-bc57-4e15-8f8c-acf51030ba6a&x=server%2520) are notes on how to convince NeverNote that you have a premium subscription:

Answer (score 1):

Older Evernote versions (before 3.0) were Windows-only shareware programs.  If you purchased the program you could export your database & synchronize it against other databases, but there was never a central server involved.

NeverNote has no automatic way of doing this or any other synchronization other than though Evernote.

I've looked at creating a local client-server synchronization for NeverNote. I'd like it for secure items, but the lack of mobile clients or a web interface would make it a pale shadow of Evernote's services. Unfortunately it won't be in the near future since my time is pretty much monopolized fixing bugs & keeping up with Evernote's clients.