# How do I convince NeverNote that I have a premium subscription?

Tags: windows-7, sync, windows-registry, evernote

I have Nixnote (NeverNote version 1.0 I believe changed name to Nixnote) and Windows 7.

I'm trying to find a way to convince Nixnote that I have a premium subscription, as shown in "[sync Nevernote (Evernote clone) notes to my own server](https://superuser.com/questions/272898/sync-nevernote-evernote-clone-notes-to-my-own-server/317439#317439)".

I went to the registry but could not find the way to do this. If anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: When you open the registry and search for NeverNote does it find anything?